# apt-get install and apt-get update not working

Tags: apt, 13.10

Whenever I am trying to install any application I'm getting the following error:

```
root@utkarsh-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/# apt-get install gksu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gksu
```

and whenever I try sudo apt-get update I get the following error:

```
root@utkarsh-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:/# sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://download.virtualbox.org saucy InRelease
100% [1 InRelease gpgv 3,435 B] [Waiting for headers] [Connecting to archive.caSplitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/download.virtualbox.org_virtualbox_debianIgn http://download.virtualbox.org saucy InRelease                             
E: GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org saucy InRelease: Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)
```

I replaced sources.list file with a new one generated from this site: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

I removed all files having 'google' or 'chrome' in their names from sources.list.d

I also uninstalled chrome still the problem persists. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that is the *full* output? Isn't there another line that you didn't show us on `apt-get update` command?

Comment: yes, this is the complete output. It asks a question but doesn't give an option for y/n, It just ends there.